# How do I programaticly navigate to a route from an event handler in React Router 4.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

I need to navigate to a route after an event is successful.
This seems to have changed since previous versions.
Previously we would do this:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
...
handleClick(){
  doSomething();
  browserHistory.push('/some/path');
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This example works in react-router and react-router-dom **v4.0.0**.

We have 3 components:

- App.js - holds both Component 1 and Component 2
- Component1.js - not wrapped in a Route and will always be rendered, but this will not have a reference of the "route props" - (history, location, match...)
- Component2.js - rendered only if the route location match. Important thing to note that this component will be rendered with "route props"

To navigate programmatically, you can use react-router [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/history) object.

`this.props.history.push('path');`

This will work right off the bat for components rendered via Route, as these components will already have access to the **route props** (history). In our example this is **Component2**. However, for components that are not rendered via a Route (e.g. Component1), you would need to wrap it in [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to give you access to the **history** object.

---

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Component1 from './Component1';
import Component2 from './Component2';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Component1 />
          <Route path="/render1" render={() => <div>Rendered from Component1</div>} />
          <Route path="/" component={Component2} />
          <Route path="/render2" render={() => <div>Rendered from Component2</div>} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

**Component1.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class Component1 extends React.Component {

  handleButtonClick() {
    this.props.history.push('/render1');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Component 1</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)}>Component 1 Button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Component1WithRouter = withRouter(Component1);
export default Component1WithRouter;
```

For **Component1**, we wrapped it in **withRouter**, and then exported the returned wrapped object. Some gotcha, notice that in **App.js**, we still reference it as **Component1** instead of **Component1WithRouter**

---

**Component2.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class Component2 extends React.Component {

  handleButtonClick() {
    this.props.history.push('/render2');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Component 2</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)}>Component 2 Button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Component2;
```

For Component2, the history object is already available from **this.props**. You just need to invoke the push function.

Comment: Thank you, your examples are more complete than the one I posted.

Comment: When I try this with Component2, I get an error in the console "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "function components" and Hooks, instead of expecting `props`, use the `useHistory()` function instead:

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function MyFunctionComponent() {
    const history = useHistory();

    const myEventHandler = () => {
        // do stuff
        history.push('/newpage');
    };

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just render a `redirect` component:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
// ...
<Redirect to="/some/path" />
```

See docs here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Redirect

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this from an event handler.  I tried setting: ```this.setState('successful',true);``` in my event handler, and then ```if(this.state.successful) return (<Redirect to="/dogs"/>);``` in my render function, but now I get an "Invariant violation" in the event handler.

Comment: You mean `this.setState({ successful: true })` I guess

Comment: Yep, I guess that would do it 

Comment: If you suggest this answer on the other question I made, I'll mark it as correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011694/invariant-violation-setting-state-in-apollo-mutate-callback

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate CodinCat's answer since he helped me resolve a different error, but I found a more correct solution:

In React Router 4.0 (I don't know about previous versions) the router passes a history object to the component (i.e.: this.props.history).  You can push your url onto that array to redirect:

```
this.props.history.push('/dogs');
```

In my case though, I had two levels of components, the router called a component called LoginPage, and LoginPage called a component called Login.  You'll only have the history object in the props of your child object if you pass it on:

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/dogs" component={DogsPage}/>
  <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
</Router>

const LoginPage = (props) => {
  // Here I have access to props.history
  return (
    <div>
      <Login history={props.history} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Login = (props) => {
  function handleClick(){
    // Now we can simply push our url onto the history and the browser will update
    props.history.push('/dogs');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to Navigate</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I know the example above is a bit contrived, since it would be easier in this case to just use a link, but I made the example this way to keep it concise.  There are many reasons you may need to navigate this way.  In my case, I was doing a graphQL request and wanted to navigate to the home page once a person had successfully logged in.